# where is ifconfig on suse studio

Tags: opensuse, sles, ifconfig, susestudio

Does anyone know where ifconfig is for SLES made in SUSE studio?

It does not exist in any of the main repositorys, or in the included repos for ZYPPER. As well it cannot be found in /sbin/zypper where it normally is for suse linux.

Answer (score 8):

That particular program was "deprecated" in favor of a different package versus `net-tools` according to discussion last year in this page: *[openSUSE Tumbleweed net-tools vs net-tools-deprecated](http://www.freetechie.com/blog/opensuse-tumbleweed-net-tools-vs-net-tools-deprecated/)*, and says the equivalent is

```
ip a
```

Further reading:

- [net-tools](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/net-tools)
- [ip - show / manipulate routing, devices, policy routing and tunnels](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html)
- [10 Useful “IP” Commands to Configure Network Interfaces](http://www.tecmint.com/ip-command-examples/)